# Converting video Using ffmepg and error :Unable to parse option value "high"

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

This is the command that I'm using to convert a video to FFmpeg :

```
$this->ffmpegAddress -i $this->input -vcodec libx264 -vprofile high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:720 -threads 0 -acodec libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k $outPut 2>&1
```

since I changed my VPS ,I got the following error for that line " Unable to parse option value  "high" " .
This is the whole Output

> FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat
>   4.4.5-6) configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab libavutil 50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1 libavcodec 52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
>   libavformat 52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2 libavdevice 52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
>   libavfilter 1.19. 0 / 1.19. 0 libswscale 0.11. 0 / 0.11. 0 libpostproc
>   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0 Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vids_temp/289590714006202.mp4': Metadata: major_brand : isom
>   minor_version : 512 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41 encoder :
>   Lavf56.40.101 Duration: 00:00:13.19, start: 0.-36281, bitrate: 355
>   kb/s Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 384x288 [PAR 1:1 DAR
>   4:3], 221 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc Stream #0.1(und):
>   Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s Unrecognized option
>   'preset'error

What's wrong with that ?

Comment: `0.6.5` is ancient and unsupported. See [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for static build or see [compile guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos).

Comment: It is quite old version. you should download latest version and try again.